# Weird conundrum involving $directives $parsers & $formatters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive to format phone numbers in a format which we desired but I'm running into an interesting problem. If the user clicks back into the middle of the input box and adds a character that the `$parser` formats out such as a , the `scope.format` function never gets called. So the phone number is valid as far as the app is concerned but the view never gets updated to remove the space. I can't update the view value directly in the parser b/c the view value isn't supposed to mirror the model value.

CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/coreysnyder/pen/WxjENg?editors=1111

```
angular.module('fakeApp').directive('vrFormatPhone', ['$compile',function($compile) {
return {
  require: ['ngModel', '^form'],
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    var lastVal = "";

    scope.inputCtrl = ctrl[0];
    scope.form = ctrl[1];
    var name = attrs['name'];
    var errorSpan = angular.element('<span ng-show="form[\''+ name + '\'].$touched && form[\''+ name + '\'].$error.minlength" class="text-danger">This field must be at least 10 characters</span>');
    elem.after(errorSpan);
    $compile(errorSpan)(scope);

    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
      scope.format();
    });

    scope.format = function(){
      var origVal = elem.val().replace(/[^\w]/gi, ''); // Remove all dashes, periods, spaces, etc
      origVal = origVal.replace(/[ ]?x[ ]?/gi, ''); // Remove x for extension
      if(origVal == lastVal){
        return;
      }

      var phone = "";
      var ext = "";

      if(origVal.length >= 10) {
        var str = origVal.substr(0,10);
        ext = origVal.substr(10, 5); // Limit extension to 5 digits
        str = str.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1-"); // Add a dash every 4 digits...
        phone = str.slice(0, -2) + str.slice(-1); // ...but remove the last dash so it's not 614-306-558-5

        if(ext.length > 0){
          phone += ' x ' + ext;
        }

        scope.inputCtrl.$setViewValue(phone); // Set the view value
        scope.inputCtrl.$render();
      }else{
        scope.inputCtrl.$setValidity('minlength', false);
      }
      lastVal = origVal;
    };

    // Use $parsers to format the value from view to model
    scope.inputCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
      value = value.replace(/-/g,'');
      value = value.replace(/\./g,'');
      value = value.replace(/ /g,'');
      value = value.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
      return value;
    });
  }
};
 }
]);
```